# Inserting values into table on table valued function where column name is a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, insert

I'm trying to convert a stored procedure into a multi-statement table valued function and i've come across the following piece of code inside a while loop, that changes the contents of `@fields` on every iteration.:

`INSERT INTO @BarrierData (@fields) VALUES (@values)`

I know for a fact that all possible values that could feed into the @fields variable represent a column defined in the table to be returned by the function.

However, I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@fields'. Expecting '.', ID, PSEUDOCOL or QUOTED_ID.

So, for each iteration of the while loop, let's say that `@fields = a` on the first iteration, 'b' on the second iteration and so on, i'd be expecing it to insert @values into column 'a' on the first run, insert @values on column 'b' on the second run, and so on.

Is there a way to make this work?

I did not write the original SP, and while I somewhat understand what it does, my knowledge of SQL is rather limited to rewrite it from scratch

EDIT: see below the code for the original procedure, and an example string that may be passed to it.

SP:

```
CREATE TABLE #prodvalues
(
      IndexDef varchar(15)
    , BarrierType varchar(15)
    , SubType varchar(15)
    , BarrierLevel float
    , Strike float
    , PayOnBarrier char(1)
    , PayOnStrike char(1)
    , PayOnStrike2 char(1)
    , CrossDate date
    , StartDate date
    , EndDate date
    , [Lower] float
    , [Upper] float
    , Payoff float
)

SET @proddata = REPLACE(@proddata,'"','')
IF LEFT(@proddata, 10) = '|ASSETBAR|'
BEGIN
    DECLARE @proddata2 varchar(max)
    IF CHARINDEX('AssetBarrList', @proddata) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @proddata2 = SUBSTRING(@proddata, CHARINDEX('AssetBarrList', @proddata), LEN(@proddata))
        SET @proddata2 = SUBSTRING(@proddata2, 1, LEN(@proddata2) - CHARINDEX(']', REVERSE(@proddata2)) +1)
        SET @proddata = REPLACE(REPLACE(@proddata, @proddata2, ''), '|ASSETBAR|', '|EBARR|')

        SET @proddata = SUBSTRING(@proddata,CHARINDEX('(',@proddata),LEN(@proddata))
        SET @proddata = REPLACE(REPLACE(@proddata,'(',''),')','')
        DECLARE @fields varchar(max) = ''
        DECLARE @values varchar(max) = ''
        WHILE LEN(@proddata) > 0
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @temp varchar(100) = LEFT(@proddata,CHARINDEX(' ',@proddata,CHARINDEX(':',@proddata)))
            SET @fields = @fields + ',' + REPLACE(LEFT(@temp, CHARINDEX(':', @temp)-1),' ','')
            SET @values = @values + ',''' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@temp, CHARINDEX(':', @temp)+1,LEN(@temp)),'"','') + ''''
            SET @proddata = SUBSTRING(@proddata,CHARINDEX(' ',@proddata,CHARINDEX(':',@proddata)),LEN(@proddata))
        END
        SET @fields = SUBSTRING(@fields,2,LEN(@fields))
        SET @values = SUBSTRING(@values,2,LEN(@values))
        EXEC ('INSERT INTO #prodvalues (' + @fields + ') VALUES (' + @values + ')')

        SET @proddata2 = REPLACE(@proddata2, 'AssetBarrList', '')
        
        WHILE @proddata2 LIKE '%|ASSBARDEF|%'
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @tmpproddata varchar(max) = @proddata2 
            DECLARE @nxtpos int = CHARINDEX('|ASSBARDEF|', @proddata2, 10)
            IF @nxtpos = 0 SET @nxtpos = CHARINDEX(')', @proddata2)
            SET @proddata = SUBSTRING(@proddata2, 1, @nxtpos) 
            SET @proddata = SUBSTRING(@proddata,CHARINDEX('(',@proddata),LEN(@proddata))
            SET @proddata = REPLACE(REPLACE(@proddata,'(',''),')','')
            SET @fields = ''
            SET @values = ''
            WHILE LEN(@proddata) > 0
            BEGIN
                
                SET @temp = LEFT(@proddata,CHARINDEX(' ',@proddata,CHARINDEX(':',@proddata)))
                DECLARE @fld varchar(max) = REPLACE(LEFT(@temp, CHARINDEX(':', @temp)-1),' ','')
                IF @fld = 'BarrType' SET @fld = 'BarrierType'

                SET @fields = @fields + ',' + @fld
                SET @values = @values + ',''' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@temp, CHARINDEX(':', @temp)+1,LEN(@temp)),'"','') + ''''
                SET @proddata = SUBSTRING(@proddata,CHARINDEX(' ',@proddata,CHARINDEX(':',@proddata)),LEN(@proddata))
            END
            SET @fields = SUBSTRING(@fields,2,LEN(@fields))
            SET @values = SUBSTRING(@values,2,LEN(@values))
            print 'INSERT INTO #prodvalues (' + @fields + ') VALUES (' + @values + ')'
            EXEC ('INSERT INTO #prodvalues (' + @fields + ') VALUES (' + @values + ')')
            SET @proddata2 = REPLACE(@proddata2, @tmpproddata, '')
            --print @proddata2
        END

    END
END
IF LEFT(@ProdData, 7) = '|EBARR|'
BEGIN
    SET @proddata = SUBSTRING(@proddata,CHARINDEX('(',@proddata),LEN(@proddata))
    SET @proddata = REPLACE(REPLACE(@proddata,'(',''),')','')
    SET @fields = ''
    SET @values = ''
    WHILE LEN(@proddata) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @temp = LEFT(@proddata,CHARINDEX(' ',@proddata,CHARINDEX(':',@proddata)))
        SET @fields = @fields + ',' + REPLACE(LEFT(@temp, CHARINDEX(':', @temp)-1),' ','')
        SET @values = @values + ',''' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@temp, CHARINDEX(':', @temp)+1,LEN(@temp)),'"','') + ''''
        SET @proddata = SUBSTRING(@proddata,CHARINDEX(' ',@proddata,CHARINDEX(':',@proddata)),LEN(@proddata))
    END
    SET @fields = SUBSTRING(@fields,2,LEN(@fields))
    SET @values = SUBSTRING(@values,2,LEN(@values))
    EXEC ('INSERT INTO #prodvalues (' + @fields + ') VALUES (' + @values + ')')
END
SELECT * FROM #prodvalues
```

Example string:

```
|ASSETBAR| (IndexDef:  PayOnStrike:"N" PayOnStrike2:"N" Strike:0.0 Payoff:0.0 Lower:0.0 Upper:0.0 AssetBarrList:[|ASSBARDEF| (StartDate:"20120619" EndDate:"20190619" IndexDef:[1mEUReur1m] BarrType:"EUS" SubType:"DOWN_IN" PayOnStrike:"Y" PayOnStrike2:"N" Strike:0.0091 Payoff:0.0 Upper:0.0 Lower:0.003 )] )
```

Comment: Was that exactly the code that you found in the stored procedure? Or was it part of dynamic SQL construction where `@BarrierData`, `@fields` and `@values` are placeholders in a string (or they are concatenated with the string segments around them) to pass a statement to `sp_executesql`?

Comment: The original code was `EXEC ('INSERT INTO @BarrierData (' + @fields + ') VALUES (' + @values + ')')`. But then i got an error saying `Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'EXECUTE STRING' within a function.`  I've tried creating a string and running `EXEC sp_executesql @qry` (it doesnt let me use the sp_executesql without the EXEC before it). With this i can save the function and run it. but when i run it, i get the error `Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.`

Comment: So this is actually inside a *function* **not** a stored procedure, @pontedm ? `FUNCTION`s and stored `PROCEDURE`s are *not* the same thing.

Comment: @ThomA, the original code is a for procedure. But I'm trying to convert it/replicate it into a table valued function. The issues i'm facing are on the function.

Comment: You need to *explicitly* list your columns and values: `INSERT INTO @TableVariable (ColumName1, ColumnName2) VALUES (@FirstValue, @SecondValue);`

Comment: Just to expand on Thom A's comment.   SQL Server does NOT support macro substitution... that would require dynamic SQL which is not permitted in a function.

Comment: As the error message tells you, user-defined functions cannot have side effects. It will not be possible for you to use `EXEC` or `EXECUTE` to invoke `sp_executesql` from within a user-defined function.

Comment: The problem is that the column name comes from a string passed to the function. to list them explicitly in the inserts, they'd always need to be in the same place in the string, which is not alwyas the case. in some cases, column 'a' might be in the begining of the string, in other cases it might be in the middle, and in others, in the end.

Comment: The table type parameter/variable **must** have an explicit definition, @pontedm, so what you are stating cannot be true. `@BarrierData` cannot be defined without defining explicit columns for it, so you *do* know what those columns are.

Comment: You probably need to step back and look at an alternative way to write this function. For example, can the block of data to be inserted be supplied by way of a JSON blob (or XML blob), so that you could use `OPENJSON()` to shred it (or `node()` and `value()` for XML) while inserting it into your `@BarrierData` table variable?

Comment: The columns are defined yes.  The string passed to the function will only contain columns that are in the @BarrierData table. The problem i'm facing with explicitly listing the column on the INSERT inside the loop is that i'm "forcing" the insert of a value into column 'a', but the value parsed is actually for column 'f'. the columns themselves don't change. what changes is their position in the string passed to the function. in the procedure it's not a problem because it allows for the column name to be a variable, which is also parsed from the string

Comment: Why do you need to rewrite it at all? And why into a function specifically? I think there seem to be a bit of a knowledge gap between the task at hand and the executor

Comment: @siggemannen, no doubt there is a knowledge gap, but i need to make due. i need to be able to use the results from the procedure, inside a view. the procedure itself returns a table but i can't just join it to the rest of the view

Comment: *"what changes is their position in the string passed to the function."* This is your problem then, fix this. Or, better yet, don't use strings to pass multiple values; use a table type parameter to start with, or use multiple variables. The fact, however, that you have an `INSERT` into a table variable means you have a multi-line function anyway so I would suggest not going down this path anyway. Use an **inline** table value function

Comment: @ThomA i need to. This is how the data is stored in the DB, and is passed by the user. The software that usually consumes this data, handles it just fine, but any ad-hoc processes that may require it, will need to break down this string.

Comment: You need to fix the process, not the function, @pontedm . If your users are giving parameters in the wrong order *stop* them doing that with better application code that forces them to provide the parameters in a *strict* order, or puts them in the correct order after they have provided them. This is turning into more and more of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) the further we "dive" (It might even be an XY*Z* issue at this stage...).

Comment: Oh ok, now that i see whole definition, yeah, it's doable, but you can't just copy the code from procedure, because dynamic sql is not allowed in functions. Instead just try to parse the string into the proper fields

Comment: I concur with @AlwaysLearning , you need to step back and rethink this. The process you are using for data entry is fundamentally broken, and really needs to be fixed from the application end first. If you still want dynamic data insert then use XML or JSON, both of which can be used in an inline Table Valued Function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "ported" this code to table function:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION dbo.FN_PRODDATA_GET
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FN_PRODDATA_GET(@proddata NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @prodvalues TABLE
(
      IndexDef varchar(15)
    , BarrierType varchar(15)
    , SubType varchar(15)
    , BarrierLevel float
    , Strike float
    , PayOnBarrier char(1)
    , PayOnStrike char(1)
    , PayOnStrike2 char(1)
    , CrossDate date
    , StartDate date
    , EndDate date
    , [Lower] float
    , [Upper] float
    , Payoff float
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @t TABLE (fieldName sysname, value nvarchar(max))
    
    SET @proddata = REPLACE(@proddata,'"','')
    IF LEFT(@proddata, 10) = '|ASSETBAR|'
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @proddata2 varchar(max)
        IF CHARINDEX('AssetBarrList', @proddata) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @proddata2 = SUBSTRING(@proddata, CHARINDEX('AssetBarrList', @proddata), LEN(@proddata))
            SET @proddata2 = SUBSTRING(@proddata2, 1, LEN(@proddata2) - CHARINDEX(']', REVERSE(@proddata2)) +1)
            SET @proddata = REPLACE(REPLACE(@proddata, @proddata2, ''), '|ASSETBAR|', '|EBARR|')
            
            SET @proddata = SUBSTRING(@proddata,CHARINDEX('(',@proddata),LEN(@proddata))
            SET @proddata = REPLACE(REPLACE(@proddata,'(',''),')','')
            DECLARE @fields varchar(max) = ''
            DECLARE @values varchar(max) = ''
            WHILE LEN(@proddata) > 0
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @temp varchar(100) = LEFT(@proddata,CHARINDEX(' ',@proddata,CHARINDEX(':',@proddata)))
                SET @fields = REPLACE(LEFT(@temp, CHARINDEX(':', @temp)-1),' ','')
                SET @values = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@temp, CHARINDEX(':', @temp)+1,LEN(@temp)),'"','')-- + ''''
                INSERT INTO @t (
                    fieldName,value
                )
                SELECT  @fields, @values
                SET @proddata = SUBSTRING(@proddata,CHARINDEX(' ',@proddata,CHARINDEX(':',@proddata)),LEN(@proddata))
            END
            SET @fields = ''--SUBSTRING(@fields,2,LEN(@fields))
            SET @values = ''--SUBSTRING(@values,2,LEN(@values))
            
            -- Transfer them
            INSERT INTO @prodvalues (
                IndexDef, BarrierType, SubType, BarrierLevel, Strike, PayOnBarrier, PayOnStrike, PayOnStrike2, CrossDate, StartDate, EndDate, Lower, Upper, Payoff
            )
            SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'IndexDef' THEN value END) AS IndexDef
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'BarrierType' THEN value END) AS BarrierType
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'SubType' THEN value END) AS SubType
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'BarrierLevel' THEN value END) AS BarrierLevel
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'Strike' THEN value END) AS Strike
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'PayOnBarrier' THEN value END) AS PayOnBarrier
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'PayOnStrike' THEN value END) AS PayOnStrike
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'PayOnStrike2' THEN value END) AS PayOnStrike2
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'CrossDate' THEN value END) AS CrossDate
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'StartDate' THEN value END) AS StartDate
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'EndDate' THEN value END) AS EndDate
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'Lower' THEN value END) AS Lower
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'Upper' THEN value END) AS Upper
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'Payoff' THEN value END) AS Payoff
            FROM    @t
            
            DELETE  @t
            
            SET @proddata2 = REPLACE(@proddata2, 'AssetBarrList', '')
            
            WHILE @proddata2 LIKE '%|ASSBARDEF|%'
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @tmpproddata varchar(max) = @proddata2 
                DECLARE @nxtpos int = CHARINDEX('|ASSBARDEF|', @proddata2, 10)
                IF @nxtpos = 0 SET  @nxtpos = CHARINDEX(')', @proddata2)
                SET @proddata = SUBSTRING(@proddata2, 1, @nxtpos) 
                SET @proddata = SUBSTRING(@proddata,CHARINDEX('(',@proddata),LEN(@proddata))
                SET @proddata = REPLACE(REPLACE(@proddata,'(',''),')','')
                SET @fields = ''
                SET @values = ''
                WHILE LEN(@proddata) > 0
                BEGIN
                
                    SET @temp = LEFT(@proddata,CHARINDEX(' ',@proddata,CHARINDEX(':',@proddata)))
                    DECLARE @fld varchar(max) = REPLACE(LEFT(@temp, CHARINDEX(':', @temp)-1),' ','')
                    IF @fld = 'BarrType' SET @fld = 'BarrierType'
                    
                    SET @fields = @fld
                    SET @values = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@temp, CHARINDEX(':', @temp)+1,LEN(@temp)),'"','')
                    INSERT INTO @t (
                        fieldName,value
                    )
                    SELECT  @fields, @values
                    
                    SET @proddata = SUBSTRING(@proddata,CHARINDEX(' ',@proddata,CHARINDEX(':',@proddata)),LEN(@proddata))
                END
                
                INSERT INTO @prodvalues (
                    IndexDef, BarrierType, SubType, BarrierLevel, Strike, PayOnBarrier, PayOnStrike, PayOnStrike2, CrossDate, StartDate, EndDate, Lower, Upper, Payoff
                )
                SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'IndexDef' THEN value END) AS IndexDef
                ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'BarrierType' THEN value END) AS BarrierType
                ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'SubType' THEN value END) AS SubType
                ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'BarrierLevel' THEN value END) AS BarrierLevel
                ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'Strike' THEN value END) AS Strike
                ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'PayOnBarrier' THEN value END) AS PayOnBarrier
                ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'PayOnStrike' THEN value END) AS PayOnStrike
                ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'PayOnStrike2' THEN value END) AS PayOnStrike2
                ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'CrossDate' THEN value END) AS CrossDate
                ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'StartDate' THEN value END) AS StartDate
                ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'EndDate' THEN value END) AS EndDate
                ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'Lower' THEN value END) AS Lower
                ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'Upper' THEN value END) AS Upper
                ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'Payoff' THEN value END) AS Payoff
                FROM    @t
                
                DELETE  @t
                SET @proddata2 = REPLACE(@proddata2, @tmpproddata, '')
            END
        END
    END
    IF LEFT(@ProdData, 7) = '|EBARR|'
    BEGIN
        SET @proddata = SUBSTRING(@proddata,CHARINDEX('(',@proddata),LEN(@proddata))
        SET @proddata = REPLACE(REPLACE(@proddata,'(',''),')','')
        SET @fields = ''
        SET @values = ''
        DELETE  @t
        WHILE LEN(@proddata) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @temp = LEFT(@proddata,CHARINDEX(' ',@proddata,CHARINDEX(':',@proddata)))
            SET @fields = REPLACE(LEFT(@temp, CHARINDEX(':', @temp)-1),' ','')
            SET @values = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@temp, CHARINDEX(':', @temp)+1,LEN(@temp)),'"','') --+ ''''
            
            INSERT INTO @t (
                fieldName,value
                )
            SELECT  @fields, @values
            SET @proddata = SUBSTRING(@proddata,CHARINDEX(' ',@proddata,CHARINDEX(':',@proddata)),LEN(@proddata))
            END
            INSERT INTO @prodvalues (
                IndexDef, BarrierType, SubType, BarrierLevel, Strike, PayOnBarrier, PayOnStrike, PayOnStrike2, CrossDate, StartDate, EndDate, Lower, Upper, Payoff
            )
            SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'IndexDef' THEN value END) AS IndexDef
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'BarrierType' THEN value END) AS BarrierType
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'SubType' THEN value END) AS SubType
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'BarrierLevel' THEN value END) AS BarrierLevel
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'Strike' THEN value END) AS Strike
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'PayOnBarrier' THEN value END) AS PayOnBarrier
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'PayOnStrike' THEN value END) AS PayOnStrike
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'PayOnStrike2' THEN value END) AS PayOnStrike2
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'CrossDate' THEN value END) AS CrossDate
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'StartDate' THEN value END) AS StartDate
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'EndDate' THEN value END) AS EndDate
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'Lower' THEN value END) AS Lower
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'Upper' THEN value END) AS Upper
            ,   MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'Payoff' THEN value END) AS Payoff
            FROM    @t
        END
    RETURN
END

GO

-- Test code
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.FN_PRODDATA_GET('|ASSETBAR| (IndexDef:  PayOnStrike:"N" PayOnStrike2:"N" Strike:0.0 Payoff:0.0 Lower:0.0 Upper:0.0 AssetBarrList:[|ASSBARDEF| (StartDate:"20120619" EndDate:"20190619" IndexDef:[1mEUReur1m] BarrType:"EUS" SubType:"DOWN_IN" PayOnStrike:"Y" PayOnStrike2:"N" Strike:0.0091 Payoff:0.0 Upper:0.0 Lower:0.003 )] )') x
```

Basically, i just changed the handling of fields / values by inserting them separately into a @temporary table and then pivoting them all at once. This removes the need for dynamic SQL.

It seems to work with the supplied test data, but of course it needs more testing. I also didn't bother optimizing code any, leaving it as exercise for the reader